# Question about the altering the multinomial theorem

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

So as I understand it the multinomial coefficient helps us make a deduction about a problem of the following type:

In how many ways can the letters of POODLE be rearranged. And so the idea is that all the letters can be rearranged in 6! ways, but then since the two Os are indistinguishable they can be interchanged, and what we have is $\frac{6!}{2!}$.

Now what I am thinking is that if we consider the two Os to be as one box, we can think of the whole word to be changed to P[OO]DLE. And we can then consider how many different ways this can be rearranged which is 5!. This is obviously wrong, since the textbook mentions that the correct answer is what I have written above. But what is the flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: Compare rearranging $P\infty DLE$.  In every rearrangement one of the characters is $\infty$.  Reinterpreting $\infty$ as $OO$ you see that every one of those rearrangements you counted you had both $O$'s next to each other and never separate.  Indeed, the number of arrangements where both $O$'s are necessarily together and not apart will be $5!$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this:

```
1. POODLE 
2. PODOLE 
3. PODLOE 
4. PODLEO
```

If you had only one O how would you count the above result?

If you had PODLE then yes - you have 5! possibilities. In other words, don't confuse 2 O that are indistinguishable (POODLE and POODLE are the same since O1 and O2 are the same o) with 2 Os that are next to each other.

So yes, the result would be  $\frac{6!}{2!}$ and not $5!$.